# Unlinking outlet from the switch

Tags: circuit-breaker

I have a dimmer switch which is also controlling the outlet. Now when I dim the light and something is plugged in the outlet my ceiling lights start flickering. I want to make my outlet always hot.
Attached are the pictures of wiring.
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: No pictures shown.

Comment: Hi, in addition to posting images, please give your location (country) so we know what sort of electrical source we're dealing with.  Also: was it this way when you moved in, or have you done some equipment replacment on your own?

Comment: Added the pictures. It's in US.

Comment: It is this way only since I moved in.

Comment: Heh, your thumb happens to be blocking the most important part of that outlet picture... A normal outlet will have a small tab that connects the two screw contacts on each side of an outlet.  Is that tab in place or has it been broken off?  Is the top and bottom of the outlet both switched or is it only half switched?

Comment: Does the dimmer control both sockets of the outlet?

Comment: @JPhi1618 yes both are controlled by a switch. The tab is there.

Comment: If we assume the red wire on the bottom of the outlet comes from the dimmer and the top and bottom of the outlet are connected with the tab, then that black wire leaving the outlet is also switched.  So where does that go?  Is there another switched outlet?  Is there a bundle of black wires (or a single black) that are not connected to the outlet?  I really expected the outlet to be half-switched after seeing that picture.

Comment: @JPhi1618 yes there is bundle of black wires tied together. Attached the pic

Comment: Your finger is still covering up what we need  to see, which is the presence or absence of a metal tab  connecting the brass screws.  Unfortunately, answers are junping the gun

Comment: What country are you in?  We need to know the way the main power feed & return (and ground, if any) reach the switch and the outlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is easy

Fortunately, it appears that always-hot is present at the receptacle location in your case, so fixing the daftness the prior installers pulled (NEC 404.14(E) prohibits dimming general-purpose receptacles if nothing else does, for reasons that range from mere flickery lights to appliances that express their displeasure at being dimmed by getting rather...hot under the collar) is no great challenge for you.

Simply remove all the wires from the receptacle, attach a white pigtail (12AWG stranded THHN always works for pigtails in general wiring if you don't know what to get) to the existing white wires with a suitable wirenut, use another wirenut to attach the black and red wires that went to the receptacle together, undo the taped splice of the two black wires, use another wirenut and a black pigtail to pigtail off of that, and wire up the receptacle with the black pigtail on a brass screw, the white pigtail on a silver screw, and the bare ground pigtail on the green screw.  Button everything back up, turn the power back on, and enjoy your now not-so-dim receptacle!

Comment: Thanks @ThreePhaseEel. Sorry I am a newbie. So lil confused. There are 2 black wires which are taped together. So I take out on of them and wire it in receptacle and tape the another one ? Also, the existing black and red which are going into the receptacle need to be wired together into wirenut ? There are 2 white wires going into outlet. So need to wire them together with a pigtail ? Thanks.

Comment: @Krishnasharma -- the two white wires get connected to a white pigtail with a wirenut after being unhooked from the receptacle, the black and red wires that were connected to the receptacle get nutted to each other, and then the lonely taped black wire has its tape removed, and then there's just black, white, bare left to connect to the receptacle.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are 3 black wire in the junction box. One is connected to the receptacle and other two are tied together and taped.

Comment: @Krishnasharma -- edited the answer to take that into account

Comment: Also, use a new receptacle.  They are $2 and in general shouldn't be reused when doing this kind of work

Comment: Since three phase pointed out that a dimmer on an outlet is a code violation and the possible fix +, follow his advice or remove the dimmer. If you cannot figure out his instructions get a pro, it won’t take a sparky long but the cost will be better than the insurance company denied clams for non code compliant wiring if a fire , just saying.

Comment: Got it done. Now the the outlet is always hot and dimmer is working as expected. Thanks @ThreePhaseEel